# The Normal Force

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, newtonian-gravity

I have a doubt regarding the Normal force.

Is it derived from Newton's Third Law of Motion?

I feel like it might, but it is not always equal to the Gravitational Force.

Please clear my doubt.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, I used gravity as an example.

Comment: The normal force is a constraint force, so to find the normal force you must take the free body diagram

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it derived from Newton's Third Law of Motion?

I don't believe it is derived from Newton 3, though some say it is a direct consequence of it. But like all forces, it exists in pairs per Newton 3.

> I feel like it might, but it is not always equal to the Gravitational
>   Force.

You are correct it does not always equal the gravitational force.

The normal force is the component of a contact force that is perpendicular to the surface that an object contacts. Normal forces prevent contacting objects from penetrating one another, due to interatomic repulsive forces that are electrostatic in nature. While typical examples of normal forces involve gravity, gravity is not necessarily involved.

For example, if I push horizontally on the surface of a vertical wall, I am exerting a normal force on the wall. It exerts an equal and opposite normal force on me per Newton 3. No gravity is involved. What's more, if the maximum static friction force between my feet and the floor, which opposes the force the wall exerts on me, is not exceeded, the net force on me is zero and I do not slip (accelerate) per Newton 2. If the wall is firmly secured to the floor to opposed my force, there is no net force on it either, so it does not accelerate.

Normal forces do not necessarily involve equilibrium (net force equal zero) as in the above example. Suppose, for example, I was pushing horizontally against the vertical surface of a box on the floor. I am exerting a normal force on the box. If the force I exert on the box exceeds the maximum static friction force between the box and the floor, there will be a net force on the box causing it to slip (accelerate), per Newton 2. Per Newton 3 the box exerts an equal and opposite normal force on me. If the force the box exerts on me does not exceed the maximum static friction force between my feet and the floor, I will not slip (accelerate) per Newton 2. The end result is a net force on the box causing it to accelerated per Newton 2.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Ask Different. You are correct its a result of Newton's 3rd law but is not always equal to the gravitational force. It is usually proportional to the gravitational force. In the figure below the normal force is perpendicular to the gravitational force but is given by $N = normal\ force = m\cdot g\cdot\sin(\theta)$

[image]

Comment: I'm thinking that in this example, the normal force will depend on the horizontal components of the other forces which are necessary to support the picture frame in this position.  One example would be a single vertical force acting at the center of gravity; in which case N = 0.

Comment: N won't equal 0 it will equal value shown in the drawing. I omitted several forces in the drawing to make it easier to see the normal force and the cause.

Comment: *"Welcome to Ask Different"* Should we feel hurt, or was this an open relationship from the beginning?